# How can I run PowerPoint 2011 (v.14.01) for Mac in "windowed" mode?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

I want to run a power point presentation in a window instead of full screen. I don't want any of the UI to show, just the presentation itself. How can I play a presentation without UI as if it's fullscreen, but in a window so I can run it side-by-side with another app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138307

> 1. Open an existing presentation or create a new one.
> 2. On the *Tools* menu, click *Customize*, and then click the *Commands* tab.
> 3. From the Category list, click *View*.
> 4. Find the "Slide Show in a Window" button and drag it to one of your toolbars.
> 5. Click Close.
>
> When you click the button, your Slide Show runs in a window and
>   follows the settings in the Slide Show dialog box.